# Is the expression, “I was the admissions mistake” grammatically right?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was drawn to the phrase “I was the admission mistake” in the following passage in the article of the *Washington Post* (May 2) titled, “As Ben Carson bashes Obama, many blacks see a hero’s legacy fade”.

> After the speech (at Yale University), H. Wesley Phillips, 27, followed (Ben) Carson’s path and began to study neurosurgery.
>
> “I had come from a public school in Tulsa and came from a single-parent household and thought **I was the admissions mistake**,” said Phillips. “But he gave me the comfort to know that if I did struggle — and I thought I would — that I wouldn’t have been the first, and there are ways to handle it. The message he gave was this backup artillery when times were hard.”

From the [*Washington Post*](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/as-ben-carson-bashes-obama-many-blacks-see-a-heros-legacy-fade/2015/05/02/b9ce53c8-e850-11e4-9767-6276fc9b0ada_story.html).

I don’t have a problem with “I’m a dropout,” but I’m somewhat uncomfortable with the expression, “I was the admissions mistake.” A person makes a mistake, but can a person be the (admissions) mistake? Is it grammatically right?

By the way, does “the” (not "an") mean “of Yale” here? If the admissions represents for the Yale's department responsible for admission, why is it "the admissions mistake" with *admission* in plural form? Isn't it "the admission's mistake"?

Comment: You're right that this is worded awkwardly, but it's not so bad as you think. Here, "*Admissions*" (note the plural: it is significant) is being used as a proper noun: the dept of the university responsible for deciding which applicants to *admit* (i.e. allow to enroll). There is still a problem though: I would strongly prefer *an* to *the*: "an Admissions mistake" makes a lot more sense than "the Admissions mistake", unless a mistake by Admissions had been previously mentioned or introduced.

Comment: @Dan: or else there is a quota for Admissions mistakes! Like "the charity child". Even so, I had no difficulty parsing the lower-case "the admission mistake" in the text. The title as displayed in the main-page menu was harder, though.

Comment: @Dan Bron I once had a boss who, whenever he issued an important report, would gather his staff around, hand them all a copy and challenge them to find *the deliberate mistake*. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with *the admissions mistake*. Perhaps the Admissions Chief always let through one under-performing candidate as a challenge to the teaching staff to find him or her.

Comment: @WS2 Was there *always* a deliberate mistake in those reports? And always just one single mistake and no more? Anyway, it's a clever way to get your staff to read your reports carefully. I once heard the reason Van Halen's standard venue contract demanded there always be a bowl of M&Ms out, *with all the brown ones removed* wasn't the whim of a gang of spoiled children, but rather an easy way for he band to determine if the venue had *read the contract carefully. If they saw brown M&Ms, they'd second guess whether [the needed electrical systems were up to snuff](http://bit.ly/1j1IKVd).

Comment: @Dan - The definite article works fine, although _an admissions mistake_ might be more straightforward. The way it's worded in the original, though, I would elaborate like this: _Every year, admissions lets in one person who they probably shouldn't – I thought I was that year's admission mistake._ It's not meant to be an exact number, though; rather, it's just something hypothetical. It's not unlike, "Every family has a crazy uncle..."

Comment: @J.R. You're the third person to suggest that, but it seems to me like a retroactive justification for what is probably a typo or minor usage error. I say that because I think it's far-fetched that the school had a one-deliberate-mistake-pear year policy, or even that Phillips was sketching a *hypothetical one*.

Comment: Other than, perhaps, the use of "the" rather than "an", the sentence makes perfect sense, so long as you understand that "admission mistake" is used with a sense of sarcasm to mean someone who was admitted in spite of presumed rules that would have prevented it.

Comment: @Dan - Far-fetched or not, I think it's a bit pedantic to call that a "usage _error_." I can think of similar usages of the definite article, like: _Jared was the problem child of the class, Dan was the class clown, and Damita was the teacher's pet_ (even though classes don't always have one and only one problem child, funny guy, or teacher's pet). The use of the definite article isn't limited to cases where the noun has been "previously mentioned or introduced;" we can say, "Bob plays the violin, the lion is king of the jungle, and my favorite poem is the sonnet."

Comment: @J.R. Yes, but I'm not sure if those last three examples are of quite the same thing as saying *She was the teacher's pet* or *He was the bright but lazy child*. I think *We live in the age of the computer* is a different speech figure.  Edwin (below) describes the former as a form of metonymy. I think the latter is just a way we have of referring to all things of that type - *the motor-car, the fast-food outlet, the smart-Alec remark etc*.

Comment: @WS2 - Sure, of course. But I was addressing what Dan said in his initial comment: _"an Admissions mistake" makes a lot more sense than "the Admissions mistake", **unless a mistake by Admissions had been previously mentioned or introduced_.** Those last three examples are addressing that part of the comment. (Over on ELL, people get confused all the time because of statements like that. I just wanted to clarify that we don't need that aforementioned "previous mention" to use a definite article.)

Comment: @J.R. You may take it on faith that I am not confused about the situations in which the definite article is used ;)

Comment: @Dan - I never thought you were. But you may take it on faith that statements like the one you made can [confuse English learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647), and  [quite often have](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles).

Comment: @J.R. Yes you do have to speak English well, usually as a native, to understand subtleties of this kind. A Swiss lady (French native speaker) who started English at school (i.e.not speaking it as a bi-lingual child) might grasp it.(though I think the same principle applies in French anyway) But she is easily the best non-native speaker I have ever known. She actually worked for me for about 3 months before it occurred to me that she wasn't English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Google "You were not a mistake" you will find that this usage is very common.

Logically, it should certainly be "You are not [just] the result of a mistake", but this device (a form of metonymy) is common and often carries impact because of its jarringness (though it can be carried to ridiculous extremes):

> It was a proud day for her parents.
>
> He sauntered to the local and had a quiet pint.
>
> I was the admissions mistake [*for* I had only been accepted into Yale
>   because someone in admissions had made a great blunder].

(Here, the first two examples are so institutionalised that they lack punchiness; this is appropriate for the second sentence. When an adjective (an epithet) grammatically qualifies a noun other than the person or thing it is actually describing, as in the first two examples, it is known as a transferred epithet {or hypallage}.)

Comment: In the days when I was a school governor I was once talking among a group of parents about the injustices of the old 11+ system, which like me you MAY remember, and the way that it tended to reject children from less than literate families. One of the parents piped up with *I was that child*. You are right about it being a form of metonymy.