# Can items themselves be mandatory, or only their related processes?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I distinctly recall being told that "**uniforms are not mandatory, but the wearing of them is**". The person was explaining that (in their opinion) many people get this wrong. They went on to say that *exam questions* aren't mandatory, but *filling them in* is.

I recently discussed this with my girlfriend – we're both interested in grammatical subtleties – but I couldn't find anything on the internet to support what I believe is the correct view on this.

Comment: In both cases the verb is implicit.

Comment: Don't dictionaries supply example sentences that support the transferred usage?  eg [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandatory) :' ... mandatory video recordings of interrogations were introduced'. Would the teacher accept _a quiet pint_?

Comment: It's a joke.  How can you wear a uniform without possessing one?

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mandatory): 'mandatory retirement age of 65.' (not _'age at which it is mandatory that people retire_'. /  [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2015/oct/12/bike-helmets-compulsory-seattle-amsterdam-cycling-safety): 'In Seattle, helmets have been mandatory for 12 years – but many cycling advocates argue such laws discourage cycling.' /  [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/02/nyregion/memories-of-koch-by-times-reporters-who-covered-him.html): 'In short order, the posters became mandatory'.

Comment: See [this thread concerning _hypallage_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244230/is-the-expression-i-was-the-admissions-mistake-grammatically-right/244232#244232).

Comment: I saw some usage examples, but not enough to convince me.

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory:

It makes sense as a joke. Your friend is being hyper-literal: *Wearing* uniforms is mandatory. *Answering* questions is mandatory.

The *act* is mandatory, not the *object*. You can't order a uniform to do something. You can order someone to do something with a uniform.

But we know what to do when we're told that that uniforms are mandatory.

Comment: S/he has become a "not sure which" pronoun used to be "politically correct" in written work.  It is a gender neutral usage.  See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/s-he

Answer (score 1):

"Mandatory" is an adjective that modifies a noun (things or processes), indicating an obligation.

In your examples:

> "[U]niforms are not mandatory, but the wearing of them is."
>
> "[E]xam questions aren't mandatory, but filling them in is."

The implied modification is that "wearing" in the first sentence and "filling" in the second sentence is "mandatory".  The reference to the nouns "uniforms" and "exam questions" as not being "mandatory" does not mean that those nouns (things) cannot be mandatory, the negative aspect is used there to set up the following clause.

The adjective "mandatory" placement can modify its noun before the noun or after verbs of to be as a predicate adjective.